# Bluetooth LE RFC

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I cannot find any protocol specification for BTLE, HCI socket buffers format for advertising/communication GAP/GATT. 
Is there any RFC as (as for example; socks5 rfc1928), or all the HCI bits and pieces are only in the messy bluez code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

please see Core specification suppliment CSSv6 for examples of advertisement data format (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications).

volume 3, part C, section 11 of the core specification 4.2 contains Advertising and scan response data format.

[image]